# "I've been to London recently" vs "I went to London recently"?

Tags: tense, present-perfect, past-simple

> I've been to London recently

or

> I went to London recently?

I was asked which of the two is correct and after thinking about it a for a bit I think I prefer the simple past version because "recently" tells us, more or less, when the action took place.

Is my reasoning sound?

Thanks guys and girls!

Comment: Why would either of them be wrong? What makes a difference here is the context and the intention behind those sentences? The context would make it clear which one should be used in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

There is a discussion of these two forms on StackExchange English Language and Usage:
[StkXch ELU "been" vs. "gone"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69077/went-to-vs-have-been-to)
"The difference is not in the action, but in where your focus is: on the present state or the past action."
The present state is having the trip in your past. The past action is that you went.
That's a sample. There's a lot more discussion.